# Looking for direction - load-balancing dovecot-postfix

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, load-balancing, dovecot

Just looking for a direction to go.  There are several HA/load-balancing packages for Ubuntu 10.04 and I'm not sure which one to use.  Here is my scenario:

Using Postfix for smtp, dovecot for pop/imap.

Two servers:

In normal operation I want one server to respond to smtp and the other to pop/imap.

If any server fails I want the other to respond to both smtp and pop/imap.

WHICH LOAD BALANCER/HA PACKAGE SHOULD I USE?

Looking for one that is the easiest to set up while still allowing different routing depending on incoming port.

NOTES:

I have file replication already set up, I'm using gluster.  This will replicate the email files between servers.

MySQL is a separate server that we are already using for our production postfix/dovecot authentication.
WWW is also a separate server we're using for our webmail/postfixadmin service, using the aforementioned MySQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keepalived for high availability. You can define two VIPs: one for each service smtp and pop/imap. One node can be configured as master for smtp and the other can be configured as master for pop/imap. When any node fails, boths VIPs are assigned to the remaining node.

Also, keepalived supports several load balancing algorithms and can be configured with failover and check scripts.

Comment: I've decided to use corosync/pacemaker for HA and keep all the services as a fail over group.  Decided not to go with replication but rather mounting an nfs share from our (windows) file server.  I have a question posted on that if you want to take a look at it. http://serverfault.com/questions/354410/dovecot-maildir-on-windows-2008r2-nfs-share