# Dovecot, maildir on Windows 2008r2 NFS share

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dovecot, centos6, nfs

I'm really banging my head on this one.  I have a CentOS 6.1 running postfix/dovecot accessing a Windows 2008R2sp1 NFS share.  In a test where the Windows server is a stand-alone file server, I can process email no problem.  Once I try to do the same in a CLUSTERED 2008r2sp1 file server all that dovecot seems to be able to do is create the domain folder and account folder beneath that - not the cur, new, or tmp folders. Dovecot gives this error:

```
Error: chdir(/var/vmail/xxx.com/xxx/) failed: Permission denied (euid=5000(vmail) egid=5000(vmail) missing +w perm: /var/vmail/xxx.com/xxx/, euid is not dir owner)
```

And in the shared folder I see the xxx.com directory and xxx subdirectory, but nothing inside the xxx subdirectory

The Windows NFS share has the following checked

NFS ADVANCED SHARING
 - No Server Authentication
 - Enable unmapped user access
 - Allow anonymous access UID 5000 GID 5000 (mapped to an AD domain user)

NFS SHARE PERMISSIONS
 - All Machines
 - Read-write
 - Root access allowed
 - ANSI

This share was set up the same on the standalone development server as it is in the server cluster.  All file server systems are 2008r2sp1.

Any help or insightful questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error message again. It says "euid is not dir owner" which means "the user with the id 5000 is not the owner of the directory".

Correct that. Authentication is not the problem here. Authorization is.

On the other hand: **Don't do** NFS that way with Dovecot! See http://wiki2.dovecot.org/NFS for details. And then NFS is no native service on Windows, which means another pitfall. I - personally - would never ever trust this kind of setup.